# how to add cordova plugin to steroids app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, plugins, steroids

I'm using [cordova-http](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP) plugin in a Steroids app. according to [manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20191025053718/http://docs.appgyver.com:80/tooling/build-service/plugins/configuring-custom-plugins/), I've added plugin in iOS config in steroids could service:

```
[
  {"source":"https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.git"}
]
```

and also I've added it in config.xml:

```
<js-module src="www/cordovaHTTP.js" name="cordova-HTTP">
  <clobbers target="cordova-HTTP" />
</js-module>
```

but still I got the [error](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/modulerr?p0=cordovaHTTP&p1=Error%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.27%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253DcordovaHTTP%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520%28native%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A20%253A494%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A21%253A502%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A267%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520%28http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520%28http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A284%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520%28http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290%29%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520%28http%253A%252F%252FmyApp.local%252Fvendor%252Fangular%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A207%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20%28native%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:34:97%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20%28http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:7:290%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20%28http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:33:207%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:33:284%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20%28http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:7:290%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20%28http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:33:207%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ec%20%28http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:36:309%29%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20%28http://myApp.local/vendor/angular/angular.min.js:18:170) telling me injected Angular model is missing.

1. do I need to link it to index.html knowing that manual says
   `<js-module>` fulfills this job.
2. do I need to install plugin like what's mentioned in plugin's github
   page:

   cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.git
3. may you please tell me what should I do step by step to make it
   work?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to add plugins. There's an easy way:

1. open your command line
2. path/to/your/project/plugins
3. cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP.git
4. Inject the plugins by adding 'cordovaHTTP' 
   Example: var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate',    'cordovaHTTP']);
5. Use it with key word cordovaHTTP

Hopes it'll help you